# A question about $t^x \equiv 1 \pmod {q\#}$ where $t,x$ are integers and $q\#$ is a primorial.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primorial

Let $t,x$ be positive integers and $q$ be any prime.

I was told that you can solve for $t^x \equiv 1 \pmod {q\#}$ by solving for each prime factor of $q\#$ and then setting $x$ to the least common multiple of the solution for each prime.

For example, for $t=13$ and $q=7$, we have:

- $13^1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$
- $13^1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$
- $13^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$
- $13^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$

So, since $4$ is the least common multiple, it follows that:

$$13^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {7\#}$$

Could someone explain why this is true?  I checked the wikipedia article on [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) but didn't see any details on this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $a^n-1|a^{k\cdot n}-1$ for every $k\geq 1$  .
Suppose that $p_i|t^{x_i}-1$ for $i=1,\cdots ,k$.
If $x$ denotes the least common multiple of the $x_i$ ,there exists a natural number $k_i$, with $x=k_i\cdot x_i$.
So, $t^{x_i}-1|t^x-1$ which means that also $p_i|t^{x}-1$ for every prime number $p_i$.
This leads us to a proof that $p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_k|t^x-1$

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation!  :-)